# Consume messages from Kafka topic through API Service Endpoint

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, event-handling, kafka-consumer-api, event-listener

Currently I have an API Service endpoint (written in .netcore6 C#)  which will accept the message object and saves it to database and then publishes that message to kafka topic-2.

How do I make use of my API Service endpoint to always listen/watch and connect to the kafka topic-1 and as soon as the new messages are in kafka topic-1 then look for the new messages and then consume the messages one by one and pass the message to the API Service endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You'd use a Kafka consumer for this, not an "API endpoint".

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet

Comment: Thank you for the inputs @OneCricketeer What are the options to deploy this Kafka consumer code on Azure AKS environment. Please share me ideas.   Thanks

Comment: I have added kafka consumer class to my API service. how to trigger the Kafka consumer to look for when ever the new messages are in kafka topic then pick/consume the messages one by one and process it?

Sample here:

Comment: Please don't use comments to add code. AKS deploys containers, so create a Docker image with c# kafka consumer code, using the linked repo, and deploy it into AKS. The consumer defaults to read latest messages. This is how Kafka consumers work. You don't "trigger it" other than calling subscribe method.

Comment: Take a look at the web example -  https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/tree/master/examples/Web

Comment: Thank you for sharing the details. 

Instead of Docker image with c# kafka consumer code, can't I deploy my API service with Kafka consumer code in it  to AKS container to see the results. Please advise?

Comment: As said, AKS runs containers. You cannot "deploy C# code" straight to AKS, to my knowledge. For that , you should use Azure WebApps, not AKS

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I mean I will deploy my API service code to one of the pod as an image in the AKS. Hope this should work. Correct me I am wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing your thoughts.
I was able to make the kafka consume functionality working in my localhost. For testing purposes, I will deploy my code to Azure Dev environment to one of the pod in Resource group as an image in the AKS and verify the behavior.

If everything is working as expected I will promote it to QA environments.

Thanks
Vamshi